# Create a DokuWiki in French

Tags: localization, dokuwiki

I am stuck with this for some time, and very surprised I cannot find the answer !

How do you build a dokuwiki in French ?

I actually managed to install the DokuWiki pretty easily.

All in English !

If possible, I would be happy to remove the English, but I can live with it.

Currently the translation is not proposed on te DokuWiki I created.

My current guess is I have to put  the translation menu on the left hand side, but still unsure..

Comment: you need to login as admin, configure and change a parameter.
I was expecting to to it at installation.
SOLVED !